# Why my Session Scope Bean throws "No thread-bound request found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, javabeans

In my Spring Boot I'd want to implement authentication via a session scoped bean.

```
@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class AuthService {
    private User user;
    public boolean isLoggedIn() { return user != null; }
    ...
}
```

I defined a filter to run on every request so that I'm able to check if the user is logged or not:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthService service;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain ch) {
        if (!service.isLoggedIn()) {
           ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

By the time the application calls `service.isLoggedIn()` I get the exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.authService': Scope
> 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
> scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a
> singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
> thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
> outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
> the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
> a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
> running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use
> RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose

I suspect I'm designing this wrongly. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to declare a bean for RequestContextListener somewhere

```
@Configuration
public class ContextListener {
    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

and then you can start using session-scoped and request-scoped beans from a singletone-scope (default) bean.